# How to avoid duplicate default configuration for Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions, code-duplication

I'm trying to implement some customization for a WebExtensions add-on, but I'm running into code duplication: both the options UI script and the content script need to know the default values for each setting, and AFAIK I can't expect either of them to be run before the other. Is there an elegant way to ensure that the local storage is initialized before either of them run?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If the storage is never set, the `default-value-1` and `default-value-2` will be used.

```
let settings = await browser.storage.local.get({
  option1: "default-value-1",
  option2: "default-value-2"
});
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get

Comment: That isn't what I asked, but it's a neat way to simplify applying any defaults.